How can I select HTML elements which are rendered after DOM
I want to select OKBTN
let main = document.querySelector("#main");
let okBtn = document.querySelector("#ok");

function myAlert(title,msg,icon){
    let card = "";
    card += `<div class="card">
        <img src="${icon}.jpg">
        <h1>${title}</h1>
        <p>${msg}</p>
        <button id="ok">OK</button>
    </div>`;
    
    main.innerHTML = card;
}

okBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
main.style.display = "none";
});

myAlert("Title","MSG","icon")
Showing Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at imggal.html:88:5

Query okBtn in myAlert and add the eventlistener in that same function.

can we use addEventListener() in template Literals?

No, do it after you've added the card to the DOM. If you want to listen clicks on a not-yet-existing element, read about event delegation.

I used this technique, working fine
OK

That's an awful way to attach event listeners on the page.

**NOW ITS WORKING FINE**

let main = document.querySelector("#main");
let btn = document.querySelector("#btnMyAlert");
    
function myAlert(title,msg,icon){
    let card = "";
    card = `<div class="card">
        <img src="${icon}.jpg">
        <h1>${title}</h1>
        <p>${msg}</p>
        <button id="ok" onclick="handleClick()">OK</button>
    </div>`;
    
    main.innerHTML = card;
}

const handleClick = () => {
main.style.opacity = 0;
};

btn.onclick = () => {
main.style.opacity = 1;
myAlert("Title","MSG","icon");
}


Because the tag does not exist at first, it returns undefined
I suggest putting the code inside a function and then hooking the event tag property to the function
let main = document.querySelector("#main");

function myAlert(title,msg,icon){
    let card = "";
    card += `<div class="card">
        <img src="${icon}.jpg">
        <h1>${title}</h1>
        <p>${msg}</p>
        <button id="ok" onclick="e => handleClick(e)">OK</button>
    </div>`;
    
    main.innerHTML = card;
}

const handleClick = e => {
main.style.display = "none";
});


Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (imggal.html:94:23)

im sorry, I will fix it now
